# Confused about key bind "C-("

Tags: key-bindings

Stupid question, but: how to press `C-(` (this is a default bind in Prelude Emacs for Smartparens's `sp-backward-slurp-sexp`)? On my keyboard i have such bracket only in same key with `9`.

Comment: Hold control and shift and then press 9?

Comment: @Tyler damn, rly seems to work, but i thought control+shift is another one modifier, cuz i have C-S-<up> and other arrows for buffer-move.

Comment: `C-(` is the same as `C-S-9`

Comment: @Tyler thx for explanation. One more thing: so i cant make smth like C-S-P (or other uppercase letter)? And maybe u will post ur comment as answer? i think this can be helpful for newcomers like me.

Comment: @Tyler I thought so and just tried out.. `C-S-9` will not work; it has to be `C-(`.

Comment: @Flowneee To figure out the key notation, do `C-h c` followed by the key combination you need to bind something to. If something is already bound, you will see that that is, or you will simply see that that combination is not bound to anything. For example, if you do `C-h c` followed by Ctrl+Shift+9 in an `emacs -Q` session, you will see `C-( is undefined`. So you need to bind your command to `(kbd "C-(")`.

Comment: @KaushalModi I don't understand - how do you type `C-(` if it's not `C-S-9`?

Comment: @Tyler I meant that you won't be able to bind commands using `(kbd "C-S-9")`, it has to be `(kbd "C-(")`.

Comment: @KaushalModi ok, but that's a different issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a convention when describing key bindings in text. `C` indicates the control key, `M` the meta key (the alt key on most keyboards), and `S` indicates the shift key. The shift key is not normally listed explicitly. Instead, you would refer to the symbol that you get when holding the shift key.

For instance, the command `set-mark-command` is bound to `C-@`. To actually type this key, you would press `C-S-2`. Or in your example, `C-(` is entered by pressing `C-S-9`. (this assumes you're using a US keyboard, where `@` is on the `2` key, and `(` is on the `9`)

One other note: for key combinations that combine the control key and a letter, the shifted letters do the same thing as the unshifted letter by default. That is, `C-S-a` (`C-A`) is the same as `C-a`. The same is true for meta. Meta + a shifted letter (eg. `M-S-a`) does the same as meta + the unshifted letter (e.g., `M-a`).

However, if you wish you can change this by explicitly binding the shifted letter to a different command. See the manual section [(emacs) Modifier Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html) for more details on this.

Finally, note that all of this is in reference to how we *communicate* about key bindings. As @KaushalModi points out, when it comes time to actually *make* a keybinding in your init file, you don't include the `S-`, you actually enter the shifted key. That is, you use

```
(kbd "C-(")
```

and not

```
(kbd "C-S-9")
```

Comment: I'd like to add that the convention is to use `S` when doing something like Ctrl + Shift + <alphabet>. So in the case of "Ctrl + Shift + p", it would be `(kbd "C-S-p")`. So rather than remember rules when to use or not use `S` in the bindings, it's better to just do `C-h c` (or `C-h k`) followed by the key combination you are interested in binding, to get the correct key notation.

Comment: .. and for "Alt + Shift + p", it is `(kbd "M-P")` :)

Comment: @KaushalModi actually, for Ctrl + letter, it doesn't matter if you use `S-` or not, captials and lower case letters are always treated the same. I didn't realize that before!

Comment: Hmm, but I do have [`M-f` and `M-F` bound to different things](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/9535bad795798d6d00495247e987361013ecefb4/setup-files/setup-navigation.el#L271-L274) and they call different commands as I would expect.

Comment: Just to clarify, the shift version of ctrl/meta key combination will do the same as the non-shift version **until** you bind them separately. Example: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-B") #'forward-word)` and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-n") #'previous-line)`. So the "the shifted letter always does the same thing as the unshifted letter." phrase in your answer would not always be true.

Comment: @KaushalModi Ctrl and Meta are different in this respect. You can't bind `C-a` and `C-A` to different commands, ever. You can with `M-a` and `M-A`. I will try to come up with clearer text for that.

Comment: You CAN bind `C-A` and `C-a` to different commands; just that `C-A` is the wrong representation; `C-S-a` is the right one. Try out `(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-n") #'previous-line)` in `emacs -Q`; `C-n` will do `next-line` but `C-S-n` ("C-N") will do `previous-line`.

Comment: @KaushalModi I stand corrected! That may be a documentation bug.

Comment: Alright, I've filed a [bug report (#23247)](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23247).

Comment: It should be pointed out, perhaps, that `C-(` is *not* the same as `C-S-9` on all keyboards. On my Norwegian keyboard, for example, it is `C-S-8` instead. Accordingly, one has to be careful when specifying these key chords.